# 404 with spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

hi
I am going through my first lessons with spring 3.I created a dynamic web app in eclipse with the following structure.

```
spring3mvc \src\my.spring.HelloWorldController.java
                \WebContent
                   |
                   |-----WEB-INF\jsp\hello.jsp                     
                   |-----index.jsp
                   |-----WEB-INF\web.xml
                   |-----WEB-INF\spring-servlet.xml
                   |-----WEB-INF\lib\...*.jar files
```

I created the spring-servlet.xml as below

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
             xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"   
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
                 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="my.spring" />
        <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        p:suffix=".jsp">

          <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        </bean>
      </beans>
```

and coded the controller

```
package my.spring;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
 @RequestMapping("/hello")
 public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
  String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
  return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
 }
}
```

index.jsp has a link to hello view

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>

</body>
</html>
```

finally in hello.jsp I have put

```
<html>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml has

```
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When I run the app on Tomcat6 server( thru eclipse),I can see the index page at
http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/ .It displays the link to hello page.When I click on it(http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/hello.html),I get a 404 error.

```
message /Spring3MVC/hello.html
description The requested resource (/Spring3MVC/hello.html) is not available.
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

thanks

mark.

Comment: I have an idee, please check my enhanced answer.

Comment: Does the mapping message occoures after adding <mvc:annotation-driven />?

Comment: Thanks Ralph for your consistent help.I was able to get the app running..There was some problem with the order of entries in xsi:schemaLocation ,but I was able to get things right.Many thanks to org.life.java for the detailed config info and advise..

Comment: the main bug was that web.xml was in WebContent folder not  WebContent/WEB-INF.that was foolish..should have been more careful while following a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the problem is not the View resolver (it would print other exceptions).

Read the error message carfully, it tells what the problem is:

```
message /Spring3MVC/hello.html description 
The requested resource (/Spring3MVC/hello.html) is not available.
```

It is that the hello **.html** (handler) can not be found, not the jsp. -- But I don't know what the exact problem it. -- I tryed to reproduce the error, but I did not get exact the same error message.

**added -- find the problem**

When you start the Server it prints all mappings to the controller in the log file. In your case there must by something like

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/hallo] onto handler 'halloController'
```

If you don't have such a statement, then something is wrong with your context scan, or you have forget to enable the annotation driven MVC @Controller programming model. This can be enabled by adding:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
```

Comment: You can check this, if you add some system.out.println message to your controller method.

Comment: I added System.out.println("message="+message); in the helloWorld() method of controller.However,I could not find that output when I ran the application.I have pasted the console output from eclipse on this url   http://pastebin.com/nkduFui4

Comment: So the problem analysis is correct -- you have a problem with mapping the request to your controller.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance..but is it <annotation-driven /> or <mvc:annotation-driven /> ? I tried the later.Still the error persists.(I have updated the spring-servlet.xml in question)..

Comment: I tis <mvc:annotation-driven />, mvc is the xml language prefix. You could skip the prefix if http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc yould be your "default" namespace for the xml document. But in your case the "default" is "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  -- so you have tor write <mvc:annotation-driven />.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure `ViewResolver`.

Here is sample configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view. InternalResourceViewResolver" >
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

When you do return `new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);` 
from above conf. it will try loading

```
prefix value + view name + suffix value
```

which will be required jsp.

Also you need to map your servlet in web.xml following way

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried that using class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" as well as InternalResourceViewResolver .Also ,I set viewClass for viewresolver as <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />  My web.xml has servlet-mapping <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>.Still I get a 404.Cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

**Steps to Recreate**

1. Open the Dashboard in Spring Tool Suite
2. Click "Spring Template
3. Project" in the "Create" area on the Dashboard
4. Right click on the newly created project in the Package Explorer pane of STS
5. SelectRun As > Run on Server
6. Choose Tomcat as your server and click Finish

**Expected Result**
The browser should launch and display the Hello World home page as defined by the HomeController > home action and the home.jsp view page.

**Actual Result**
404 Error

**The Solution**
 1. Open up HomeController.java
 2. Add a space anywhere in the file. Yeah. A space. Hit the spacebar. This is the solution. LOL
 3. Run the project again as you did before.

This gives you the expected result.

**My Hypothesis**
The HomeController class isn't compiling initially, so the component-scan method isn't finding it; making it necessary to make a change to the file, and save it. This forces the class to be compiled, and therefore makes the home controller and the /home action discoverable.

I messed around with configuration files until I was pulling my hair out. I can't even tell you what made me think to try this. ;-) Glad I got it figured out though. Hopefully the Spring MVC 3 team will look into this, as it could easily create a serious barrier to entry to an otherwise cool framework.